# How to search through the text in a JLabel?

Tags: java, html, swing, jsoup

I have a bit of code that goes to a website, finds text, and prints it out html style in a JLabel.  I want to be able to change the color of a specific word in the text ( maybe all of the word "cow" would be green).  Here is the code:

```
public void code() throws IOException
{
    Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.nbcwashington.com/weather/school-closings/").get();
    Elements tags = document.select("p");

    String txt = "<html>";
    for (Element tag : tags) {
      txt += tag.text() + "<br/>";
    }
    txt += "</html>";
    output.setText(txt);

    }
```

Comment: `txt += tag.text() + "<br/>";` should be something like `txt += tag.text().replaceAll("cow", "<span style='color: #00FF00;'>cow</span>") + "<br/>";`.  For more detailed help, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  BTW - better (more efficient) to use a `StringBuilder` than string concatenation.

Comment: Tried both ways.  For andrew's how would you add multiple things?  Sometimes the things say Closed or 
closed with lowercases and stuff like that

Comment: *"how would you add multiple things?"*  Again,a bit louder this time.. **For more detailed help, post an MCVE.**

Answer (score 2):

> I have a bit of code that goes to a website, finds text, and prints it out html style in a JLabel

I find working with JTextPane and style attributes easier than working with HTML.

Just add the text to a text pane as normal text, then you can search the text and change the attributes as required:

Untested code would be something like:

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setText(...);

SimpleAttributSet keyword = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setForeground(keyword, Color.GREEN);

StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
int length = textPane.getDocument().getLength();
text = textPane.getDocument().getText(0, length);
String search = "cow";
int offset = 0;

while ((offset = text.indexOf(search, offset)) != -1)
{
    doc.setCharacterAttributes(offset, search.length(), keyword, false);
    offset += search.length();
}
```

You can also make the JTextPane look like a JLabel by using:

```
textPane.setOpaque( false );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check value using `.equals` method .you can use span tag to color it.

```
public void code() throws IOException
{
    Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.nbcwashington.com/weather/school-closings/").get();
    Elements tags = document.select("p");

    String txt = "<html>";
    for (Element tag : tags) {
       if(tag.text().equals("cow")){
        txt += "<span style=\"color:#00FF00\">"+tag.text()+"</span><br/>";
       }else{
        txt += tag.text() + "<br/>";
       }
    }
    txt += "</html>";
    output.setText(txt);

    }
```

Comment: tnx 3rd one was a mistake

Comment: The 2nd one is a minus one, if only for the laziness.  Please save me the trouble (and change it).

Comment: i didn't get 2nd one .do u mean use replace all instead of .equals ?

Comment: No, I'm talking about both *non-code* sentences..  And please, when you do not understand something I write, ask about it, rather than ignore me.

Comment: haha i didn't igone iwas confuss and was thinking about what did u mean.non code?sorry but i didn't get it yet.do u mean use ternary operater

Comment: @AndrewThompson, in the comments I still see "tnx" and "u" and the code still uses string concatenation, instead of `StringBuilder` as was suggested. So much for tips on how to improve the answer :( -1  for promoting string concatenation.

Comment: @AndrewThompson eventually i got it.

Comment: Yay!  ..but I still prefer my method...  No stuff that, @camickr has shown the really *clever* way to approach this.  But plus one for changing the text.